# Chrome's Javascript console: what does it output in terms of objects?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

From the javascript console in Chrome:

```
> function Person(name){this.name=name;}
undefined
```

At this point, Person.prototype should be an empty Object according to the Javascript specs.
Let's assign it:

```
> p=Person.prototype
  > Person
```

Note that that > Person is clickable and it expands to:

```
constructor: function Person(name){this.name=name;}
__proto__: Object
```

But... wasn't it meant to be an empty object? What is all the extra stuff?
If you do an alert:

```
alert(p)
```

You get [object Object]. Why, when you type it in the Chrome console, does it come out with > Person which expands? Wasn't it meant to be an empty object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the `prototype` always has the `constructor` property which points to the function it is the prototype of. And of course it inherits from an object too, that is the internal `__proto__` property.

It is defined in [ECMAScript 5 Section 13.2, *Creating Function Objects*](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2):

> (...)
>
> 16. Let *proto* be the result of creating a new object as would be constructed by the expression `new Object()` where `Object` is [the standard built-in constructor with that name](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2).
>
> 17. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *proto* with arguments `"constructor"`, [Property Descriptor](http://es5.github.com/#x8.10) {[[Value]]: *F*, { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true}, and false.
>
> 18. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *F* with arguments `"prototype"`, [Property Descriptor](http://es5.github.com/#x8.10) {[[Value]]: *proto*, { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false}, and false.
>
> (...)

This means nothing else than:

Create a new empty object called *proto* (16). Define the property `constructor` on that object and set the value to *F* (the function itself) (17). Then define the property `prototype` on the function *F* and set its value to *proto*.

---

If you `alert` an object, then the object is converted to a string. The default behaviour is to convert an object to the `[object Object]` string,  unless the "special" `toString` method is overridden.

The Chrome console lists these properties because it is meant for debugging, so you need information. `[object Object]` is not very informative.

FWIW, an empty object looks like this:

[image: empty object]

You can also see the internal `__proto__` property here. An empty object *always* inherits some default properties, but it does not have **own** properties.

Comment: We need more answers like this. :)

Comment: BTW, not too fond of SO's current handling of user references in comments. :\

Comment: @FelixKling: So when Chrome shows in the console what seems like a "type", like on `someProperty: Type`, it is actually displaying the `someProperty`'s value's constructor name?

Comment: @Raphael: It seems to be like that. Only if the value is an object though.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's console is a developer tool. It is meant to show in-depth info. In this case, you're looking at the pre-defined properties of the class you just defined.

Answer (score 0):

Those are methods and properites inherited from the Object class.

[It discusses the defaults here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch08_07.htm)