# Yet another "how to find the class/constructor name of a Javascript object"?

Tags: javascript

Yes, I've seen this asked and answered before. But here's what I still don't understand:

If I create a constructor function, and don't override the function's `prototype` property, then we have the automatic `constructor` property hanging off the function's `prototype` property. That is `MyConstructor.prototype.constructor === MyConstructor` => true. Great. But now what happens when I override `prototype` with my own object, and don't patch up the `constructor` property? `constructor` now doesn't exist on `prototype`, and if referenced is only found up the prototype chain, that is `MyConstructor.prototype.constructor === Object` => true. Fine. So...

Why is it that in a Javascript debugger (like Chrome), if I override a constructor's prototype with my own object, and new up an instance of that constructor, and then type that instance variable on the command line, Chrome happily tells me the type? How does it know??? I.e. what can I do to find out the same thing through code?

Simple repro:

```
> function Foo() {}
undefined
> Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo
true
> Foo.prototype = {}
Object
> Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo
false
> f = new Foo()
Foo
> f
Foo
```

Is it pure debugger magic?

Comment: The association is still there somewhere - since `f instanceof Foo` returns `true` - but I don't think it's exposed to user code.  Whcih I guess makes it pure debugger magic.

Comment: This one seems related <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553951/chromes-javascript-console-what-does-it-output-in-terms-of-objects>

Comment: firefox seems to lack the debugger magic since the f = new Foo() and f lines both return [object Object] which the linked answer above explains

Comment: Yes @g13n, that link is related, but only talks about the part that I understand, it does not answer the question. I didn't realize Firefox doesn't display Foo. I will assume that it is in fact debugger magic, and not possible through user code, without manually storing additional data. Thx.

Comment: @curtc yep AFAIK it is not possible through userland code. Newer versions of Firefox has a JavaScript console (triggerred through Ctrl+Shift+K) on Windows, GNU/Linux. Both this console and Firebug just knows that they're objects and nothing beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is simply to *not* set the prototype to your custom object? You could loop over all of the properties of your custom object, and add them as properties to the existing prototype, therefore retaining all of the properties of the original prototype object, such as the constructor.

Comment: That, or add a property to your custom prototype object that holds a reference to the constructor function, or even simply some custom string or something that you can check...